# RSA Encrypting password with a public Modulus and exponent in Python

Tags: c#, python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I need to encrypt a password and add it as a http header to make a rest call from a python client.  I am trying to implement the following C# code listed below in Python,  but the rest POST request seems to be failing with Python as the encrypted password string generated from python does not seem to be matching the encrypted password from C# . The C# code generates the correct encrypted password

modulus: `"w1jcEfmxCTz5aB9wGg1Vl5K45VUm8Aj7+05sBarmrwbvC9BNjAqSySPmC2ajWSQGdmBs4xylKZjHKaXg5rxuNw=="`

exponent:

```
"AQAB"
```

password to encrypt:`'tricky'`

encrypted password from C#(keeps changing each time it is generated): `'%14%1d%0a%bb%a0X%24H%ad%ce%9aG%f6a%dau%d8%01%ec%d5)+%d3%11%8e%3ew%c8K%dce%ec%84K%e6%1d%ea%81%3e%d14%87%80s%8eo%a6%bc%fd%1b%8f%a1V8%c8%96%b1%ec%1f%d7qd%bbz'`

encrypted password from Python:`'%21%F6%7E.i%F4%F4%5E%E5%A9v%03E%8C%1C%3E%F1%D7%DBT%A2%03z%BF%E2%E8%8FJh%E3%85%AA%24%25%C2%C9Hg%18z%22a%F8g%0B%81%3C%DC%FEr%F8C%98s%B5%DA1%F6%60%23%BAw%10F'`

Here is my python code using Pycrypto which does the encryption:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.PublicKey.RSA import construct

def get_encrypted_password(password, modulus, exponent):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')

    # decode base64 string to be used as modulus(n) and exponent(e) components for constructing the RSA public key object
    modulus = b64decode(modulus)
    exponent = b64decode(exponent)

    n = int.from_bytes(modulus, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
    e = int.from_bytes(exponent, byteorder=sys.byteorder)

    pubkey = construct((n,e))
    encrypted = pubkey.encrypt(password,None)[0]
    #url encode the encrypted password
    encrypted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(encrypted)
    return encrypted
```

This is the C# code which does the encryption:

```
public static string EncryptForTransport(string strToEncrypt, string rsaPublicKey)
        {
            KeyContainerPermission permission = new KeyContainerPermission(KeyContainerPermissionFlags.AllFlags);

            permission.Assert();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strToEncrypt))
            { return strToEncrypt; }

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = GetRsaEncryptor(rsaPublicKey);

            byte[] buffer = rsaEncryptor.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strToEncrypt), false);

            try
            {
                rsaEncryptor.Clear();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
                //errors may occur ignore them.
            }

            string encryptedStr = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(buffer);// byteConverterGetString;

            return encryptedStr;

        }

        private static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRsaEncryptor(string rsaPublicKey)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = RSACryptoServiceProvider.Create() as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            if (rsaEncryptor.PersistKeyInCsp)
                rsaEncryptor.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaEncryptor.FromXmlString(rsaPublicKey);

            return rsaEncryptor;
        }
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong with encrypting the password using RSA in Python?

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS, that will encrypt everything.

Comment: `byteorder=sys.byteorder` is wrong, it should simply be `byteorder='big'`

Comment: You don't yet know whether you're doing the correct thing. You need to encrypt in one language and decrypt in the other in order to check compatibility, because RSA has randomized padding. Anyway, just use HTTPS with a valid server certificate. That's what Let's encrypt is for.

Comment: InterAction Rest API uses RSA encryption algorithm(Interaction Authentication) and requires the client to explicitly encrypt the password with RSA public key. The URL looks like this https://<webserver>/InterActionAPI/CRMService.svc/Contact

Comment: @JamesKPolk tried your suggestion, but didn't work .  The machine where I am running the python script from is indeed 'Little' endian. But, sys.byteorder should pick up the machine specific endianness

Comment: The `byteorder` argument is for the byte order of the data, not the byte order of your machine. Your data (n and e) is big endian.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Gotcha! Looks like that may not be the only problem as the encrypted password still seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match what the C# code is doing you must parse the big-endian modulus and exponent correctly, and use PKCS v1.5 padding. This example below modifies your code slightly to show this.

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.PublicKey.RSA import construct
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
import urllib.parse


def get_encrypted_password(password, modulus, exponent):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')

    # decode base64 string to be used as modulus(n) and exponent(e) components for
    # constructing the RSA public key object

    modulus = b64decode(modulus)
    exponent = b64decode(exponent)

    n = int.from_bytes(modulus, byteorder='big')
    e = int.from_bytes(exponent, byteorder='big')

    pubkey = construct((n, e))
    pubkey = PKCS1_v1_5.new(pubkey)
    encrypted = pubkey.encrypt(password)
    # url encode the encrypted password
    encrypted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(encrypted)
    return encrypted
```

Comment: Awesome! that did the trick .  I had tried PKCS1_v1_5 before but had the wrong byte order.  It works now.  Thanks!